# Передать i в функцию

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу передать i в функцию, что бы функция выполнялась на ровне с ходом цикла: 1,2,3,4,5

```js
var count_arr = 5;
for (var i = 0, count_arr; i < count_arr;) {
  $(function() {
    console.log(i);
  });
  i++;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `var` на `let`. Подробности см. https://learn.javascript.ru/var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так:

```js
var count_arr = 5;
for (let i = 0; i < count_arr;) {  
  (function() {
    console.log(i);
  })();
  i++;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Либо так

```js
var count_arr = 5;
for (var i = 0; i < count_arr;) {
  (function(i) {
    console.log(i);
  })(i++);
}
```